# Linear regression with errors on x and y

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I have two variables, x and y, each of which has an error in x and y associated with each point. I'm trying to fit a linear regression model in R which takes account of the error in both variables. I see that you can use weights in lm() to weight the regression based on errors but as far as I can see this can only incorporate errors on one variable. Is there any way to fit a linear model which takes into account errors on both of the variables?

Comment: Search for *"Deming regression"*.

Comment: Also *"orthogonal regression"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Stéphane Laurent for the answer.

The package "deming" contains a function to do exactly this.